# Accessing Global Session Key in Umbraco

Tags: c#, xslt, umbraco

I have a group of session keys which I declare in a Global class file, these get set properly upon login.

```
public static class SessionKeys
{
    public static string memberToken = "token";
    public static string memberFirstName = "first_name";
    public static string role_pmn = "PMNInstructor";
    public static string role_superUser = "";
    public static string role_chapterAdmin = "ChapterMember";
    public static string role_registeredUser = "RegisteredUser";
}
```

I have a need to later access some of these session vars in an XSLT Macro for navigation. I'm having trouble finding the correct syntax for accessing these variables in the XSLT Macro.

This syntax works in my .NET Macros:

```
Session[Globals.SessionKeys.role_pmn]
```

Comment: How do you run your XSLT? Anyway I suppose you can pass parameter into your XSLT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syntax for accessing the global session keys in XSLT is different than what is used to access them in C#. You merely have to use the string value you set the key to.

```
umbraco.library:Session(PMNInstructor)
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax should be 
    umbraco.library:Session

[This link](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Umbraco/Reference/umbraco.library/Session) should provide more information.

Alternatively, you could create an extension library, get the reference in .net, and then just reference your library in the xslt ([umbraco.tv video](http://umbraco.com/help-and-support/video-tutorials/developing-with-umbraco/xslt-extensions/introduction-to-xslt-extensions) for reference, or [text-only instructions](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Umbraco/Create_xslt_exstension_like_umbraco.Library_in_C))

Comment: Yes, umbraco.library:Session works for pulling back a session object i.e. umbraco.library:Session('userName'). But it's the syntax of pulling back my Global Session key that does not seem to fly.

I'll try creating an extension library.